# Find the volume between the regions $x^2 + y^2+ z^2 = 4$ and $x = 4-y^2$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I want the volume of the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4$ from $x = 0$ to $x = 4-y^2$.  The integral that gives this volume is

$$\int\limits_{-2}^2 \int\limits_0^{4-y^2} \int\limits_{-\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}\ 1\ dz\ dx\ dy$$

I don't find $T$ such that $T\bar{u} = \bar{x}$ for every $\bar{x}\in D$ where $D$ is our desired volume.

I mean, I'm trying to find $D^*$ such that for every $\bar{u} \in D^*$, $T$ is a change of variables for our problem.

So, I'm trying the find the volume between the regions $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4$ and $x = 4-y^2$ but I can neither find that scalar.

Any ideas please.

Comment: Have you considered converting to cylindrical coordinates?

Comment: $x\le\min(4-y^2,\sqrt{4-y^2}).$

Comment: @user170231 Yes, but cannot find the way to describe the set $D$. Tried $T(h, r, \phi) = (h, \sqrt{r^2-h^2} cos\phi, \sqrt{r^2-h^2} sen\phi)$, for $(h, r, \phi) \in [0, 2] \times [h, 2] \times [0, 2\pi)$.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but the surface $x=4-y^2$ is totally out of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$

Comment: What is the domain of integration? See: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rwbhv4mxx0

Comment: $\approx 16.703234$ Now true?

Comment: @Henry It is $(x, y) \in [0,1] \times [-\sqrt{4-x}, \sqrt{4-x}]$ and $(x, y) \in [1,2] \times [-\sqrt{4-x^2}, \sqrt{4-x^2}]$, right?

Comment: @Blue Tomato depends. I think just on one side ($x>0,y>0)$ it is $(x, y) \in [0,1] \times [\sqrt{4-x}, \sqrt{4-x^2}]$

Comment: @Henry I got it, depends if I was the desired volume directly, or the whole volume without those little regions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Nobody commented on my scalar in the comments section so far.

The projection of the solid on the $xy$-plane is determined by curves, $x^2+y^2=4$, $x=4-y^2$ and $x=0$. The common solution of the circle and the parabola gives $(1,\pm \sqrt{3})$. Hence the quarter volume integral due to symmetries w.r.t $xy$-plane and $x$-axis, is
$$\frac{1}{4}V=\int_0^{\sqrt{3}}\int_0^{\sqrt{4-y^2}}\int_0^{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}dzdxdy+\int_{\sqrt{3}}^2\int_0^{4-y^2}\int_0^{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}dzdxdy$$
and
$$\frac{1}{4}V=\int_0^{\sqrt{3}}\int_0^{\sqrt{4-y^2}}\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}dxdy+\int_{\sqrt{3}}^2\int_0^{4-y^2}\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}dxdy$$
and
$$\frac{1}{4}V=\int_0^{\sqrt{3}}\frac{\pi}{4}(4-y^2)dy+\int_{\sqrt{3}}^2\left(\frac{x\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}{2}+\frac{(4-y^2)\arcsin(\frac{x}{\sqrt{4-y^2}})}{2}\right)\vert_0^{4-y^2}dy$$
and hence $V$ is
$$V=3\sqrt{3}\pi+2\int_{\sqrt{3}}^{2}\sqrt{y^2-3}\sqrt{4-y^2}+(4-y^2)\arcsin(\sqrt{4-y^2})dy$$
By WolframAlpha, $V\approx 16.324+0.482=16.806$. The second integral which gives the tiny volume is not nice.

Comment: Sorry about that. The tricky step in the original problem is the integral $$\int_{-2}^{2} \int_{0}^{4-y^2} 2\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2} dx dy$$ A formal and clearly way to solve that last integral is not trivial, at least not for me neither for WolframAlpha, so it is necessary to commit a change of variables transformation. I parameterized one little region with cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: @BlueTomato This integral?: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=int+%284-y%5E2%29arcsin%28sqrt%284-y%5E2%29%29

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i2d=true&i=Integrate%5B2Sqrt%5B4-Power%5Bx%2C2%5D-Power%5By%2C2%5D%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C4-Power%5By%2C2%5D%7D%5D

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i2d=true&i=Integrate%5B2Sqrt%5B4-Power%5Bx%2C2%5D-Power%5By%2C2%5D%5D%2Cx%5D

The complete proof in the second link, even by Wolfram, is not short nor elegant as desired as with the change of variables transformation. Maybe I'm wrong. Let me know if so.

Comment: Second link... You can do this by hand. Problem starts after that.