# What is the value of $\int_{\sqrt{3}}^{2}\sqrt{y^2-3}\sqrt{4-y^2}dy$?

Tags: elliptic-integrals

I answered the volume question [Find the volume between the regions $x^2 + y^2+ z^2 = 4$ and $x = 4-y^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4578958/find-the-volume-between-the-regions-x2-y2-z2-4-and-x-4-y2/4580192#4580192).

But , then I faced two nasty integrals. One of them is $$I=\int_{\sqrt{3}}^{2}\sqrt{(y^2-3)(4-y^2)}dy.$$

Let us substitute $y=2\sin\theta$. Then,
$$I=\int_{0}^{\large\frac{\pi}{6}}4\sin^2\theta\sqrt{1-4\sin^2\theta}d\theta$$
WolframAlpha found it : https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=int_0%5E%28pi%2F6%29sin%5E2tsqrt%281-4sin%5E2t%29dt But unfortunately I can not find it that easily although I can do the complete integral by a formula. I saw the formula here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2102.09459.pdf

Any help or positive comment is appreciated. Thanks.

(Only subgenius friends can take a joke. I am writing this for friend Em.)

Comment: What about the **residue theorem**  ? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem)  This is a pair function, it could work.

Comment: Can you do it without denominators? I am not that genius. @AlbertSchrödinberg

Comment: Wolfram alpha also gives the indefinite integral. You differentiate the result to see how it connects to the integrand.

Answer (score 1):

Notation for (complete) elliptic integrals:
$$
K(k):=\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-t^2)(1-k^2t^2)}}dt,
\qquad
E(k):=\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{1-k^2t^2}}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt.
$$
By simple algebra we also have
$$
\int_0^1\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{(1-t^2)(1-k^2t^2)}}dt=\frac{K(k)-E(k)}{k^2}.
$$
Integrating by parts we get
$$
I:=\int_{\sqrt 3}^2\sqrt{(y^2-3)(4-y^2)}dy=\int_{\sqrt 3}^2\frac{2y^4-7y^2}{\sqrt{(y^2-3)(4-y^2)}}dy.
$$
We have
$$
2y^4-7y^2=-2(y^2-3)(4-y^2)+7y^2-24
$$
hence
$$
I=-2I+\int_{\sqrt 3}^2\frac{7y^2-24}{\sqrt{(y^2-3)(4-y^2)}}dy,
$$
i.e.,
$$
I=\frac 13\int_{\sqrt 3}^2\frac{7y^2-24}{\sqrt{(y^2-3)(4-y^2)}}dy.
$$
It is convenient to change integration variable by $y=2t$ to obtain
\begin{align*}
I&=\frac{4i}{3\sqrt 3}\int_{\sqrt 3/2}^1\frac{7t^2-6}{\sqrt{(1-t^2)(1-\frac 43t^2)}}
\\
&=\Re\left(\frac{4i}{3\sqrt 3}\int_{0}^1\frac{7t^2-6}{\sqrt{(1-t^2)(1-\frac 43t^2)}}\right)
\\
&=\Re\left(\frac{4i}{3\sqrt 3}\left(7\frac{K(\tfrac 2{\sqrt3})-E(\tfrac 2{\sqrt3})}{4/3}-6K(\tfrac 2{\sqrt3})\right)\right)
\\
&=\Im\left(\frac{K(\tfrac 2{\sqrt3})+7E(\tfrac 2{\sqrt3})}{\sqrt 3}\right).
\end{align*}
One can further simplify the result by splitting real and imaginary parts (see also [Separate elliptic integrals into real and imaginary parts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8859/separate-elliptic-integrals-into-real-and-imaginary-parts)). In particular we use [DLMF 19.7.3](https://dlmf.nist.gov/19.7#E3)
\begin{align*}
K(k^{-1})&=k\left(K(k)-i K(k')\right),\\ 
E(k^{-1})&=k^{-1}\left(E(k)+iE(k')-{k'}^2K(k)-i k^2K(k')\right),
\end{align*}
where $k':=\sqrt{1-k^2}$ with $k=\sqrt 3/2$, $k'=1/2$ to obtain
$$
\Im(K(2/\sqrt 3))=-\frac{\sqrt 3} 2K(1/2),\qquad \Im(E(2/\sqrt 3))=\frac 2{\sqrt 3}E(1/2)-\frac{\sqrt 3}2K(1/2)
$$
so that finally
$$
I=\Im\left(\frac{K(\tfrac 2{\sqrt3})+7E(\tfrac 2{\sqrt3})}{\sqrt 3}\right)=\frac {14}3E(1/2)-4K(1/2).
$$
This agrees with the linked computation in Wolfram Alpha (up to the factor 4 omitted in the integral and up to the different convention in the notation for elliptic integrals, which in WA are expressed as functions of $k^2$ rather than $k$, explaining the argument $1/4$ rather than $1/2$ in the elliptic integrals).

Comment: Good. Thanks. But, Is it $\approx 0.105$?

Comment: I think there is some serious mistakes.

Comment: I trust you Gulio please find the solution of WolframAlpha.

Comment: Maybe it is only because of a difference in the notation!. Wolfram Alpha uses $K(m),E(m)$ with $m=k^2$. In that notation the final equation of my answer should read $K(4/3)$ and $E(4/3)$ in place of $K(2/\sqrt 3)$ and  $E(2/\sqrt 3)$, let me know if that solve the problem.

Comment: I have updated the answer with the final result, agreeing with WA

Comment: BTW, "you check and tell me" is not the proper way to address to people who have spent time to solve your problems.

Comment: Sorry @Gilulio...

Comment: I thought you are the friend I know.